# Bash script hangs at times when using "2>&1" and "tee" in a variable

Tags: bash, ssh, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have a bash script that we are running on Ubuntu 2004 in Windows via WSL 2 that creates a tunnel to gain access to a DB. The script will attempt to connect to many of the below examples so the script needs to continue. What I have been trying to do here is run the command silently and only print if any errors occur. Regardless, the script needs to keep moving.

My issue is with `2>&1` and `tee` together. When they are used together and an error occurs, it works as expected.

When an SSH connection is attempted and works correctly, the command hangs and the echo (`echo "SSH Finished"`) is never printed.

If I remove the `2>&1` and just keep `tee`, it works in both a successful and failure, however, the failure is not caught within the variable `$ssh`

On a connection that works, but the script hangs. It appears to be the ssh servers that have a host message upon login. If I just run `ssh -N -f -o StrictHostKeyChecking=accept-new -L $LocalDBPort:"$RemoteDBHost":5432 user@"$SSHServer"` it connects and gets the command prompt correctly after printing a warning message that is roughly 15 lines long.

I've been playing with `&` as well as `-f` switches to no avail.

Any ideas on a solution or what I might have done incorrectly in the below code snip?

```
#!/bin/bash
# add -x to above to enable debug
...

exec 5>&1

echo "Start SSH"
ssh=$(echo 0 | ssh -N -f -o StrictHostKeyChecking=accept-new -L $LocalDBPort:"$RemoteDBHost":5432 user@"$SSHServer" 2>&1 | tee /dev/fd/5)
echo "SSH Finished"

if [[ $ssh == *"AccessDeniedException"* ]] || [[ $ssh == *"Could not request local forwarding"* ]] || [[ $ssh == *"failed"* ]] || [[ $ssh == *"Bad"* ]] || [[ $ssh == *"error"* ]] || [[ $ssh == *"exception"* ]] || [[ $ssh == *"Permission denied"* ]] || [[ $ssh == *"already in use"* ]]
then
    echo "$ssh"
    Connected=No
fi
```

Comment: Do you really need all those ssh options? `-N` in particular tells ssh not to run a remote command so on a successful ssh you just end up with an open session.

Comment: ...and if there's no local shell, there's nothing to read the output of `echo 0`.

Comment: I'd honestly remove the `-N` and add `'exit 0'` as an explicit remote command. Your use case is not the one `ssh -N` is built for, which is when ssh is supposed to stay open just for the sake of continuing to run forwarding. (Or are you not just testing the ability to set up forwarding, but also trying to _actually_ set up forwarding? That's a different task with different requirements).

Comment: BTW, make sure you have `ExitOnForwardFailure` enabled. The other thing I'd worry about -- but you need to check ssh's source or just strace it to see if it's a problem -- is if it's only closing stdout/stderr _when they're attached to TTYs_ when trying to background itself; if it doesn't close them when they're files or FIFOs, it'll still stay attached to the copy of `tee`. The cheap-and-easy workaround there might to be use `unbuffer` or another tool that emulates a TTY as a wrapper.

Comment: I think things like `exec 5>&1` are highly non-portable. Also `expect` is probably the tool you want to use.